# Threading in C# with limited number of jobs and limited number of active threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

I have a loop that looks something like this:

```
var list = new List<float>();
while (list.Count < wantedNumberOfJobs)
{
    var resource = ... //gets the resource
    lock (resource)
    {    
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoWork, /*wrap resource and list into an object*/);
    }
}

//continue pass this point when all the threads are finished
```

And the work method:

```
private void DoWork(object state)
{
    var list = (/*wrapperObject*/)state.List;
    var someFloat = //do the work to get the number

    lock (list)
    {
        list.Add(someFloat);
    }
}
```

Essentially I want to do a large, but a specific (given by `wantedNumberOfJobs`) number of jobs done. Each of these jobs inserts a single item into the `list` as you can see in the `DoWork` method.

I am not certain that this code is assuring me that `list` will contain `wantedNumberOfJobs` items past the designated point. I'd also like to limit the number of active threads. I've used the `System.Threading.Semaphore` class, but am not sure this is the best solution.

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you can use Parallel.For, like so:

```
Parallel.For(0, wantedNumberOfJobs, i => {
                var resource = ... //gets the resource   
                DoWork(Resource);
            });
```

Comment: This is it. Simple and elegant. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should really get a copy of [Patterns for Parallel Programming: Understanding and Applying Parallel Patterns with the .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=19222).

It explains who to use the parallel extensions in .net 4 and how you can influence how many jobs are running concurrently. For your list you should also take a look into the [Concurrent namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx) to find a thread-safe alternative.

Comment: That article is a good resource for threading. Thanks. I also found the Parallel.For in it, which Steven suggested and was the way to go.

Comment: Also I've looked at the Concurrent namespace and BlockingCollection<T>'s description seems like the one for me as I'm adding an element to the list with every DoWork(...) job. I'm just wondering if I need to lock BlockingCollection<T> when adding or does the "thread-safe" cover that?

Comment: @gligoran: You don't need a lock. Just use `Add()`, `CompleteAdding()`, `GetConsumingEnumerable()` and/or, `Take()`. But locks on your site shouldn't be needed, cause that's what the concurrent collection does internally. Just make sure you are familiar with the Producer/Consumer pattern (described in the document) to use the collection the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this C#4, consider using Tasks from the TaskPool rather than Threads from the TreadPool. This will limit the number of threads you use based on the number of processors you have. Also, consider removing some of the locks as each of them require context switching and process locking which effectively limit or even eliminate the advantage of using multiple threads in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely end up with many more than `wantedNumberOfJobs` items in `list`.  This is because the while loop is deciding whether or not to queue a new work item based on the current contents of list.  Depending on how long `DoWork` takes, it could queue hundreds or thousands of items before any are added to `list`.

One way to work around this problem is to have the while loop keep track of the number of work items it queues up, and to stop when it gets to `wantedNumberOfJobs`.

Answer (score 0):

PLINQ may be sufficient for you? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460714.aspx